# what is "both sides of a relationship must have the same number of column" error?

Tags: sql-server

hello I have nine tables in database Two of the tables in the database are:

```
tbl_unit
--------
Unit_Number(pk),
Floor_Number(pk),
Apartment_plaque(pk),
BedRoom_Count,
BathRoom_Count,
Rental_Fees_Unit,
Unit_Area,
Unit_state
```

and

```
tbl_payment
-----------
Renter_National_Code(pk),
Apartment_Plaque(pk), 
Floor_Number(pk),
Unit_Number(pk), 
Owner_National_Code,
Payment_Date,
Debt,
Other_Amounts,
Other_amounts_comment,
amount_of_payment
```

I can't determine the none of primary key's in tbl_payment as foreign key for primary key's in tbl_unit and i recieve "both sides of a relationship must have the same number of columns" error

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

A table can have only one primary key.  Your tbl_payment table has a composite primary key consisting of 4 columns while the tbl_unit table has a composite primary key of 3 columns.

I believe you want a foreign key on the tbl_payment table to relate a payment to a specific unit.  In that case, add a 3-column foreign key on tbl_payment referencing the primary key of tbl_units:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_payment
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_tbl_payment_tbl_unit
FOREIGN KEY (
      Unit_Number
    , Floor_Number
    , Apartment_plaque
    )
REFERENCES dbo.tbl_unit(
      Unit_Number
    , Floor_Number
    , Apartment_plaque
    );
```